# Playing a sound in c++ while doing other things

Tags: c++, audio, codeblocks

I have a little 2d that I want to have sounds(any format) when certain events happen, but when I use PlaySound() my game freezes until the sound is over, so I need a function that will play a sound while not freezing the program until the sound is over, please explain everything in detail, as I am not fammiliar with proffesion terms.

Answer (score 2):

Play the sound asynchronously with the `SND_ASYNC` flag, as described in [the documentation for `PlaySound()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Going forward, you'll eventually want to decouple the various bits of logic in your game, possibly with different threads to handle different things concurrently.